# Add subscriber to Mailchimp through API 3.0

Tags: c#, email, post, subscribe, mailchimp-api-v3.0

I'm attempting to integrate version 3 of Mailchimp's API to add a subscriber to one of my mailing lists. The code below is what I have thus far, and my intention is to call it in my contact form method when the user fills out their email to subscribe. In theory it should get this email stored in emailAddress and POST it to MailChimp, but theorys are not practical. Below is my current method of POST data:

```
private string InsertIntoMailChimpGeneralList(string emailAddress)
{
    var apiKey = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MailChimpAPIKeyGeneral"];
    var dataCenter = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MailChimpDataCenterIDGeneral"];
    var listId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["mailChimpListIDGeneral"];
    var email_address = emailAddress;
    var status = "subscribed";

    using (var wc = new System.Net.WebClient())
    {
        // Data to be posted to add email address to list
        var data = new { email_address, status };

        // Serialize to JSON using Json.Net
        var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data);

        // Base URL to MailChimp API
        string apiUrl = "https://" + dataCenter + ".api.mailchimp.com/3.0/";

        // Construct URL to API endpoint being used
        var url = string.Concat(apiUrl, "lists/", listId, "/members?");

        // Set content type
        wc.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/json");

        // Generate authorization header
        string credentials = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(":" + apiKey));

        // Set authorization header
        wc.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.Authorization] = string.Format("Basic {0}", credentials);

        // Post and get JSON response
        string sendUrl = wc.UploadString(url, json);

        return sendUrl;
    }
}
```

In my contact form I have a check where I want the email address added in the contact form (emailAddress is the variable used here) to post that data to the list, when the form is submitted:

```
            if (ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["UseMailChimpIntegration"].ToString().ToLower().Trim() == "true")
        {
            InsertIntoMailChimpGeneralList(emailAddress);
        }
```

I feel I've implemented this wrong. I was able to get it working on v2 but upgrading to v3 has left me clueless at this point. My contact form runs fine and stored my values in my local database, but does not POST that data through to mailchimp.

I've triple checked my API/datacenter values, and would appreciate some assistance.

Comment: Old post, only reason I'm replying is b/c I'm working on a custom API submit to MailChimp using C# as well. Besides not knowing what values are in AppSettings, I noticed was that there's no `username` in the `Basic` auth. MailChimps' documentation states that "anystring" is literally, "whatever string you want" - The Marketing API lets you use any string as the username in the user:password portion of the HTTP basic authentication request.- https://mailchimp.com/developer/marketing/docs/fundamentals/#before-you-start -- Also, it should be `wc.Headers["Authorization"] = "Basic " + credentials`